# link_to redirecting to "SHOW' method instead of "DELETE"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

```
= link_to multimedium_path(f), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete this multimedia?' } do

     i.fa.fa-trash.fa-lg.mr-2.text-danger
```

When i use link_to, the button is redirecting me to show method of the multimedia controller.
Using `button_to` solves this problem, but the `confirm` is not working properly.

```
= button_to multimedium_path(f), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure to delete this multimedia?' } do

     i.fa.fa-trash.fa-lg.mr-2.text-danger
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Thank you!!!

Comment: Make sure you don't have any errors in JS console.

Comment: please update your routes

Answer (score 0):

Probably It's about your layout html code. I had the same problem. If you deleted all the code that rails gives you for layout, it'll do this. So this is the code you need to put in your layout's which you wanna make action as destroy. Put in head tag.

```html
<head>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
       .
       .
       .
</head>
```

And this is because as you know html don't(like to idk why) destroy by itself... you need to put certain codes for example like this to make html ruthless :)